# Authenticate Multiple .NET Core Application in one Authentication Server

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, system-design

Suppose, I have two Applications, Application-A(.NET Core & Angular) & Application-B(.NET Core & React). Is it possible to secure both application's endpoints(API) using one Authentication Server?

N.B: The two applications are hosted on completely two different domains. May be for two different companies.
For Reference, attaching a diagram.

[image: Auth]

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common scenario that could be solved in multiple ways. Depending on your use case you could use existing third-party login providers ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)) or, if you want to use your own identity, use an OAuth2 server and make Application A and B OAuth2 clients.

There are commercial and open source servers available.
Since you are already using the .NET stack you might want to look at [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4).